# What is the advantages and disadvantages of writing return type java.util.Date or Date?

Tags: java

The methods is a basic part of the system core.

```
 public java.util.Date getCurDate(){...}
 public Date getCurDate(){...}
```

What is the advantages and disadvantages of writing this return type?

Comment: if you have 2 Date classes it will help to avoid conflict

Comment: Are there actually any significant advantages/disadvantages? Other than the first one `java.util.Date` being able to fully qualify the actual Date class..

Comment: no computational advantage as such...just helps to resolve conflict and confusion for both the compiler and the code reader

Comment: Maybe I'm confused but are they not the same? The top being the full path to date where the bottom is just the shorthand version of doing the same thing?

Comment: Tks, how about java.util.Date getCurDate(String format) and Date getCurDate() @FastSnail .

Comment: nice if you don't have other Date classes no advantage at all but more codes

Comment: Normally, I most use this way ....import java.util.Date; --------->public Date getCurrent(){};

Comment: There's no difference on bytecode level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return type needs to specify an unambiguous type. By using a fully qualified type name like `java.util.Date` you can be sure it won't be confused with some other `Date` class in a different package.  However if your `import` statement includes `java.util.*` or `java.util.Date` already, then just saying `Date` will be unambiguous enough and the compiler will know which `Date` you mean.

Comment: I would like to add that a fairly common one to mix up `java.util.Date` with would be `java.sql.Date`

Answer (score 0):

If there is no reason to assume there will be conflict with another class called "Date" then there is no need or advantage to write the full name.